# declaring variables in flex

Tags: variables, apache-flex, syntax

I found this in an ActionScript class in flex.

```
protected::valueMin
```

Please let me know what this exactly means. at the outset, I dont see any type declaration.
I am a newbie in flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As spash said, this syntax is used for namespaces. In this case it is actually used to workaround a compiler issue. The thing is that you can't declare an accessor in which the getter has a different scope as the setter. It is to say, you can declare it, but accessing the accessor via it's name will result in a compile error.

Consider the following:

```
private var _name:String;

[Bindable(event="nameChange")]
public function get name():String {
  return _name;
}

private function set name(value:String):void {
  if (value !== _name) {
    _name = value;
    dispatchEvent(new Event("nameChange"));
  }
}
```

If you now try to access the "name" property to get or set it, this will result in a compile error:

```
name = "John Doe";
```

However, if you specify the scope the code will compile.

```
private::name = "John Doe";
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use nowadays `name = "Jon Skeet"`? ;-)

Comment: Hehe, indeed. I swear I'll do that from now on.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a reference to the protected class member `valueMin`.

> You can reference namespaces with the
>   `use namespace` directive or you can
>   qualify the name with the namespace
>   using the name qualifier (`::`) punctuator.

see also: [Namespaces](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/03_Language_and_Syntax_06.html#118930)